# Qt thread error on debug but not in run mode

Tags: c++, qt

I got stuck on this problem a few days ago: when i go on debbuging mode, i receive this messages among others:

`ASSERT failure in QWidget: "Widgets must be created in the GUI thread.", file kernel\qwidget.cpp, line 1133
 ASSERT: "qApp && qApp->thread() == QThread::currentThread()" in file kernel\qapplication_win.cpp, line 905`

but when i go in run mode, everyting go fine. 
Beside this, the same code went last week , I have not changed it at all, but now no longer go. Can someone tell me why?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing is fine. You're creating widgets from threads other than the main thread. This will not work. It may appear to work, but it's not supported. You must fix your code. It's impossible to say how exactly to fix your code, since you don't provide any...

Comment: Not the code was the problem, i moved the method in the main cpp (in UI project ) and now is working. It was in a class from a dll that I made myself.  I think about how other methods work , since they are in dll and perhaps in another thread . :-?

Answer (score 5):

[Q_ASSERT](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_ASSERT) is a no-op in release mode.

So your doing something bad with threads, but in release mode `Qt` doesn't care as the internal asserts do nothing.